# UILocalNotification for alarm when iPhone is mute

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilocalnotification, alarm

I'm currently addding an alarm clock feature to a big app. 
What's important is that the alarm would fire even if the device is in silent mode (mute switch is on). 
(also nice to have the alarm would go off even if the app terminated).

After doing my search I understand that `UILocalNotification` is the proper way to go.

My question are:

1. Will the alert sound even in silent mode using `UILocalNotification`?
2. Is there another, maybe more proper way?(must be apple approved)
3. Are there any limitation to expect? (sound file length for example)

Comment: why not code up a quick sample app to test this?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, that's what silent mode is for.
2. UILocalNotification is the way to go for local notifications
3. Sound length is 30 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Since silence really does silence everything, even Apple's own notifications, what you can do is set multiple UILocalNotifications, similar to the messages app when you ignore the first notification, it pings you again in a minute or two.

Comment: No silent/manner mode does not silence everything. Like the staple clock app (alarms) nor earthquake alarms and I assume similar. (I've been woken up by a North Korean missile). It seems like even in 2020 (7 years later) Apple still doesn't want to support true alarm apps.